# Проблема с классом Scanner в Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, scanner

На новом компьютере установил Intellij IDEA, установил JDK, всё как положено. Но вот какая-то проблема со Scanner, не могу его использовать, какая-то ошибка... Подскажите, что тут не так и как исправить? Скрин прилагаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

`File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Project Settings` -> `Modules` -> "Your Module Name" -> `Sources` -> `Language Level`

Поставьте Language Level, который вам нужен - конкретно 1.4 или более поздний.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]